# Nginx serve static files only in subdirectories

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have image path `/uploads/{some user id}/0a17f689-b7d5-4592-a16a-85feb1ae00c7.gif`.
I want to serve this kind of path with nginx. How can I make nginx look for the file in all directories that match this pattern, but I don't want to have {some user id} in the url. So I want url like this `/uploads/0a17f689-b7d5-4592-a16a-85feb1ae00c7.gif`.

Here is my nginx.conf location:

```
  location /uploads/ {
    alias /cncdata/uploads/;
    autoindex off;
  }
```